# How to copy namespace in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

My in put file is: aa.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CSDOC xmlns:cs="http://www.google-try.com/cs"
    xmlns:ci="http://www.google-try.com/ci">
    <cs:body>
        <cs:content>
            <cs:appendix>
                <blockquote>
                    <p>
                        <text>
                            This is a text to try this programm is correct or not. <ci:cite>My name is john</ci:cite> this is a test.
                        </text>
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
            </cs:appendix>
        </cs:content>
    </cs:body>
</CSDOC>
```

My python code is:

```
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy
XMLDoc = etree.parse(open('aa.xml'))
v = '/CSDOC/cs:body/cs:content/cs:appendix/blockquote/p/text/ci:cite'
for Node in XMLDoc.xpath(v,namespaces={
       'cs': 'http://www.google-try.com/cs',
       'ci': 'http://www.google-try.com/ci',
       }):
    m2 = copy.deepcopy(Node)
    print(ET.tostring(m2))
```

Output is:

```
b'<ns0:cite xmlns:ns0="http://www.google-try.com/ci">My name is john</ns0:cite> this is a test.\n\t\t\t\t\t\t'ut
```

Desired output is:

```
<ci:cite>My name is john</ci:cite>
```

Actually i want to copy only select or xpath element content but my code is copy select content with parent element content and without namespace. please advice how to copy only xpath element content with namespace.

Comment: You are using lxml for parsing and searching, and ElementTree for serialization. That seems odd. Why don't you use `print(etree.tostring(m2))`?

Comment: Actually my requirement is copy the element through xpath and transform through xslt.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "copy the element through xpath"? And if your intent is to use XSLT, please explain that in the question; don't just mention it in a comment.

Comment: To get rid of "this is a test." (the `tail` of the `cite` element), use `print(etree.tostring(m2, with_tail=False))`. See https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring.

Comment: My question is correct at this time i want to copy only xpath element with there namespace. I have use with_tail keyword we have receive exception "TypeError: tostring() got an unexpected keyword argument 'with_tail'" why i dont know. Please suggest how to solve this.

Comment: You should use lxml for everything (see my first comment). lxml's `tostring()` method accepts the `with_tail` argument. ElementTree's `tostring()`  method does not.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is working. without any exception.